Org-mode compare column to constant string
I can easily compare strings from two columns, as in:
| hello | world | KO |
| hello | hello | OK |
| world | world | OK |
#+TBLFM: $3=if("$1" == "$2", OK, KO)

But I can't compare a column to a constant string, I think I want something like this:
| hello | OK |
| hello | OK |
| world | KO |
#+TBLFM: $2=if("$1" == "hello", OK, KO)

(I manually filled OK OK KO for this one as it does not work, it gives KO KO KO.)
Am I missing something obvious?

You can turn formula debugging on to see what's going on: C-c {. When you C-c C-c on the formula again, you will see:
Substitution history of formula
Orig:   if("$1" == "hello", OK, KO)
$xyz->  if("$1" == "hello", OK, KO)
@r$c->  if("$1" == "hello", OK, KO)
$1->    if("(hello)" == "hello", OK, KO)
Result: KO
Format: NONE
Final:  KO

so for some peculiar reason, "$1" was turned into "(hello)" with the extra parens being the reason that the equality test failed. You can try changing the constant string in your formula to "(hello)": that produces the expected results but it is hardly satisfactory.
I'm not sure whether this is long-standing behavior or a recently introduced bug. Either way, I tend to avoid the Calc if in formulas that involve strings and write the formula in Elisp, where I have explicit control over conversions:
| hello | OK |
| hello | OK |
| world | KO |
#+TBLFM: $2= '(if (string-equal $1 "hello") "OK" "KO")

